# Heroku I18 does not change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

Heroku Terminal:

```
Ruby console for vinderhimlen.heroku.com
>> I18n.l Time.now
=> "Tue, 22 Mar 2011 22:28:27 +0100"
>> I18n.locale = :da
=> :da
>> I18n.l Time.now
=> "Tue, 22 Mar 2011 22:28:54 +0100"
>>
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo, you typed I18.l instead of I18n.l.